# en una clase (ListView) en django, como mandar más de un dato por contexto? usando metodo GET

Tags: python, django, get

Tengo un problema al mandar por metodo GET y en mi template tengo un paginador de django y a parte también tengo un formulario donde viene una letra para que filtre a los usuarios. El problema es que no se como se mandaría la información en el contexto si es más de un dato.

Mi código es:

```
class ExpedientView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'portfolios'
    template_name = 'dashboard-admin/portfoliorecords.html'
    paginate_by = 10
        
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ExpedientView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        queryset = Portfolio.objects.filter(moneybox__isnull=True).order_by('owner__last_name')
        letter = self.request.GET.get('letter', None)
        if letter:
            queryset = queryset.filter(owner__last_name__istartswith=letter)
        context['portfolios'] = queryset
        context['letter'] = letter
        return context
```

si corro este código, el error que me aparece es "ExpedientView is missing a QuerySet. Define ExpedientView.model, ExpedientView.queryset, or override ExpedientView.get_queryset()"

Intenté cambiar el código usando get_queryset() y quitando get_context_data() de la siguiente manera:

```
class ExpedientView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'portfolios'
    template_name = 'dashboard-admin/portfoliorecords.html'
    paginate_by = 10
     def get_queryset(self):
         queryset = Portfolio.objects.filter(moneybox__isnull=True).order_by('owner__last_name')
         letter = self.request.GET.get('letter', None)
         if letter:
             queryset = queryset.filter(owner__last_name__istartswith=letter)
         return queryset
```

El cual funciona bien, pero por ejemplo sólo mandaría lo que hay en el queryset y también necesito que mande letter al template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema inicial `"ExpedientView is missing a QuerySet. Define ExpedientView.model, ExpedientView.queryset, or override ExpedientView.get_queryset()"` era causado por que antes del llamado a `get_context_data`, la vista llama a `get_queryset` que tiene como tarea recuperar el queryset base, a partir de este se realiza la paginación, etc. Tu idea está bien, en el primer ejemplo que tienes, estas líneas serian conceptualmente tu queryset base:

```py
        queryset = Portfolio.objects.filter(moneybox__isnull=True).order_by('owner__last_name')
        letter = self.request.GET.get('letter', None)
        if letter:
            queryset = queryset.filter(owner__last_name__istartswith=letter)
```

El problema es que la vista por defecto intenta recuperar este queryset a partir del método `get_queryset`, y este no puede finalizar por que no tienes definido tanto el argumento `queryset` y/o sobrescrito el método `get_queryset`.

En tu segundo ejemplo corriges esa parte, ahora puedes seguir sobrescribiendo el método `get_context_data` para pasar la variable letter.

```py
class ExpedientView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'portfolios'
    template_name = 'dashboard-admin/portfoliorecords.html'
    paginate_by = 10

     def get_queryset(self):
         queryset = Portfolio.objects.filter(moneybox__isnull=True).order_by('owner__last_name')
         letter = self.request.GET.get('letter', None)
         if letter:
             queryset = queryset.filter(owner__last_name__istartswith=letter)
         return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ExpedientView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['letter'] = self.request.GET.get('letter', None)
        return context
```

Comment: Ah ya entiendo, había que juntar y sobreescribir los métodos y cada uno resuelve por ejemplo el queryset y el otro ya la parte del contexto de las letras.